# How to update expiration date of cookie via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-plugins

I'd like to update the expiration date of a cookie via jQuery. I am using the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js).

Here is the code I used to set the expiration date to 8 hours into the future:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (8 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
$.cookie('myCookie', $.cookie('myCookie'), { expires: date });
```

This created a new cookie with the right name, but the wrong attributes:

- The new cookie had the value `[object Object]` instead of the original, ampersand-delimited, key-value cookie string
- No SSL (secure) flag in the new cookie (old cookie had SSL flag set to true)
- Expiration was set to when the browser is quit, instead of 8 hours into the future

What is a correct way to only update the expiration date of a cookie via jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (8 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
var myCookieValue = $.cookie('myCookie');
$.cookie('myCookie', null);
$.cookie('myCookie', myCookieValue, { expires:date, secure:true, path:'/' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents: what is your cookie initially ?

I try ot reproduce your issue with a cookie that is initialize like this:

```
$.cookie("myCookie", "myValue")
```

and it worked.

but I tried with a cookie that is initialized like this:

```
$.cookie("myCookie", {myParameter: "myValue"})
```

I don't think the cookie jQuery plugin is design to store object. You can only save string value. so When you so `$.cookie("myCookie")`, it return `"[object Object]"`

Comment: I need to keep the original value of the cookie, which is why I specify `$.cookie("myCookie")`. But this doesn't return the original value of the cookie, it returns `[object Object]`. I need the string (value) contained within the cookie.

Comment: yes, I think it returns [object Object] because you previously saved an object and not a string value. That's why I asked: "how do you store your cookie initially ?"